# Calculating the Constant of Integration in Parametric, Vector-based Equations

Tags: integration, trigonometry, vectors, parametric

I'm having trouble finding the constant of integration in parametric, vector-based equations.

Given an equation:

$$
a(t)\ =\langle \cos(t),\ \sin(t)\rangle
$$

and

$$
\int\ a(t)\ dt\ =\langle 0,\ 2\rangle
$$

for some $t$, I need to calculate the constant of integration for the $i$ and $j$ components of $a(t)$.

So, I can get as far as finding the following:

$$
\int a(t)\ dt\ =\langle \sin(t), -\cos(t)\rangle + \mathbf C
$$
$$
C_i = -\sin(t)
$$
$$
C_j = 2 + \cos(t)
$$

My hunch is I need to resolve t to some number--otherwise $C$ isn't a constant.

Any nudges in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you weren't given $\int a(c)dt=<0,2>$ for some constant $c$?

Comment: @K.Power - Yup. It was definitely  $$ \int\ a(t)\ dt\ =\ <\ 0,\ 2\ > $$

Comment: Please: Write $\langle 0,2\rangle$, not $<0,2>$.  I edited the question accordingly. $\qquad$